# How to make Vim auto-complete with / for path instead of \

Tags: vim

Currently Vim pop-ups for path completion, shows like ..\css\style.css But, backslashes doesn't work in Firefox for some reason, So, I want VIM to auto-complete as ../css/style.css (Notice, difference in slashes).

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What does vim have to do with Firefox? Why would you need them to use the same path separator?

Comment: @meagar: I guess he is trying to insert in vim something like `href='../path/to/another/file.htm'` or something like that and would like `CTRL-X CTRL-F` in vim to use slashes instead of backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set shellslash
```

?

Even on Windows, I never use `noshellslash`.

Comment: Thank you Luc, I am not the OP but vim still seems to have lots of secrets to me!